Find next High/Low in index based on a reference point variable
I'm trying to create a couple of methods that use the mark price of a given ticker and then references the next highest high or lowest low (out of four bars) based on that reference point.
Example:
Min Array - [2, 3.5, 5, 8.5, 9]
Max Array - [20, 17, 9, 7, 5]

Sample input
Mark: 3.6

Expected output
Min - 3.5
Max - 5

Then if Mark crosses above $5 or below $3.5, the result would be as follows:
Mark: 5.1

Expected Output
Min - 5
Max - 7

Or
Mark: 3.4

Expected Output
Min - 2
Max - 5

It seems that my method is able to increment the index but only in one direction. For example, if the mark drops below $2.50, the index will reference the next value but it does not return to the previous value when the mark breaks $2.50 again after dropping below it.
Please take a look and let me know what I'm missing. (FYI: ohlcv pulls the open, high, low and close values of the chosen ticker. candle[2] being the high and candle[3] being the low of the current time frame. Whenever the mark price crosses the index high, the index decrements and references the next previous four bars to find the next high. It decrements because the index is sorted from high to low. The opposite is also true for when the mark price crosses the index low.)
def compare_hl(ohlcv, mark, symbol):
    minarray = []
    maxarray = []

    low_index = 0
    high_index = 0
    # Extract the lows of all candles
    lows = [candle[3] for candle in ohlcv]
    highs = [candle[2] for candle in ohlcv]

    # Initialize variables to track the starting index of the previous four bars

    while low_index < len(lows):
        # Extract the lows of the previous four bars
        previous_lows = lows[low_index:low_index + 4]

        # Check if the mark price falls below the lows of the previous four bars
        if mark < min(previous_lows):
            # Update the starting index for the next set of previous four bars
            low_index += 4        
        elif mark > min(previous_lows) and low_index < -4:
            print("\nMark Price above Minimum of Previous Lows. Reverting to Previous Set.")
            low_index -= 4
            break
        else:
            # If mark price is not below the lows, move to the next set of four bars
            low_index += 4
        minarray.append(min(previous_lows))

    while high_index < len(highs):
        # Extract the lows of the previous four bars
        previous_highs = highs[high_index:high_index + 4]

        # Check if the mark price falls below the lows of the previous four bars
        if mark > max(previous_highs):
            # Update the starting index for the next set of previous four bars
            high_index += 4       
        elif mark < max(previous_highs) and high_index < -4:      
            high_index -= 4
            break
        else:
            # If mark price is not below the lows, move to the next set of four bars
            high_index += 4
        maxarray.append(max(previous_highs))

    return minarray, maxarray

def find_reference(mark_price, minarray, maxarray, lo_index, hi_index, lowref, hiref, crossbelow, crossabove):

    if mark_price > maxarray[hi_index]:
        crossabove = True
    elif mark_price < minarray[lo_index]:
        crossbelow = True

    if mark_price > maxarray[hi_index]:
        print(colors.CYAN + "Mark Max: ", str(mark_price), str(maxarray[hi_index]) + colors.END)
        print(colors.CYAN + "Mark has crossed above previous 4-bar Max.\nMark: ", str(mark_price),"\nMin: ", str(minarray[lo_index]) + colors.END)
        hi_index -= 1
        highreference = maxarray[hi_index]
        crossabove = True
        crossbelow = False
        print(colors.CYAN + "New High Reference Set: ", str(maxarray[hi_index]) + colors.END)
    elif hi_index <= -2 and mark_price < maxarray[hi_index + 1]:
        if not crossabove:
            print(colors.CYAN + "Mark has crossed below last high. Adjusting reference." + colors.END)
            hi_index += 1
            highreference = maxarray[hi_index]
            print(colors.CYAN + "New High Reference Set: ", str(maxarray[hi_index]) + colors.END)
            crossabove = False
            crossbelow = True

    if lo_index >= -len(minarray) and mark_price < minarray[lo_index]:
        print(colors.CYAN + "Mark has crossed below Min: ", str(mark_price), str(minarray[lo_index]) + colors.END)
        lo_index -= 1
        lowreference = minarray[lo_index]
        crossabove = False
        crossbelow = True
        print(colors.CYAN + "New Low Reference Set: ", str(minarray[lo_index]) + colors.END)
    elif lo_index <= -2 and mark_price > minarray[lo_index + 1]:
        if not crossbelow:
            print(colors.CYAN + "Mark has crossed above last min. Adjusting reference." + colors.END)
            lo_index += 1
            lowreference = minarray[lo_index]
            print(colors.CYAN + "New Low Reference Set: ", str(minarray[lo_index]) + colors.END)
            crossabove = True
            crossbelow = False

    lowreference = minarray[lo_index]
    highreference = maxarray[hi_index]

    return lowreference, highreference, lo_index, hi_index


Please [edit] your question and put there sample input (small) and expected output.

@andrejKesely I've added sample input and expected output for your reference.

There is no sample input here, unless you expect people to only look at find_reference. In that reference, simple update the example by removing the stuff we don't need and instead add some sample data to the code, so that it can be executed. You want a minimal, reproducible example here.

Your code has a bunch of issue and contains a bunch of parameters and assignments you never use. Either you cut this from a larger codebase and still left more in than was needed for the question, or you just have a lot of dead code here.
However, your question seems to be about find_reference and that can be as simple as:
def find_reference(mark, mins, maxs):
    return max(x for x in mins if x < mark), min(x for x in maxs if x > mark)


def main():
    mins, maxs = [2, 3.5, 5, 8.5, 9], [20, 17, 9, 7, 5]

    print(find_reference(5.1, mins, maxs))
    print(find_reference(3.4, mins, maxs))


main()

Output:
(5, 7)
(2, 5)

If that doesn't answer your question, you should provide some actual example data and show how you expect to call those functions, with what arguments, and what you expect as a result.

This perfectly answered my question so thank you. This was cut from a larger code base I'm working on and I apologize for the unnecessary code I provided. I'm still learning how to format my questions efficiently so please excuse my ignorance.

You're welcome. For future questions, you're likely to get the best answers if you limit your code to code you think is relevant to the problem, ideally in form where people can just copy and run it to reproduce your issue.
